# is there any way to bind the Grid View where rows having column like visualization

Tags: c#, asp.net

[This is the method where I am getting all cards image path and returning as Arraylist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOEtT.png) [This is where I am binding gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU79n.png) [I want output on browser something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB6KW.png) I am developing a web application for Poker game using asp.net web forms and c#. I have an ArrayList of card image paths.

What is the correct way to bind gridview data so that the cards will be shown side by side like a player hand? Later on I will put the logic for the no of cards etc.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the relevant code that you have. It's impossible to help you if you do not share your code.

Comment: @Radhika, go to Toolbox of Visual Studio > Search for GridView. Drag and Drop. This is where you can bind your data to.

Comment: @SamWalpole please check once now I have added snapshot of images

Comment: It would be more useful if you could paste the code into the question as text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<asp:DataList>` with `RepeatDirection="horizontal"`.